# Character falsely walking in the air?

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a horse run across a road in Unity. But, after putting every stuff in place, horse is unable to consider the road presence while crossing it (in the game mode). I mean it should walk/run over the road. What did I missed here?
[image]

For making roads , I am using [EasyRoad3D](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/987).

Comment: Can you give us some code you used or the config of the differents gameobjects?

Comment: Have you checked your NavMesh? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by setting the road material shader to **standard**.